# Jquery + gwt without GQuery

Tags: jquery, gwt

I'm trying to add the Jquery library to my project after that add tipsy.js as well for do a "plugin" with tooltips.

The thing is that i already added js in my gwt.xml file but still I can't call the "$" to jQuery

My gwt.xml file is :

```
<module ... 
  <!-- jquery and plugins -->
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/tipsy.js"></script>
```

and the method with the call in js is :

```
public static native void allClassName(String className) /*-{
  $wnd.jQuery(className).tipsy({trigger: 'focus', gravity: 'w'});
}-*/;
```

but I allways got this error:

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Object [object Window] has no method 'jQuery'
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.com$gwtplatform$mvp$client$HandlerContainerImpl_automaticBind_methodInjection_***_*_**(ClientGinjectorImpl.java)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.memberInject_Key$type$netagenda$ui$gwt$client$pages$backend$customers$presenter$CustomerPagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1395)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.create_Key$type$netagenda$ui$gwt$client$pages$backend$customers$presenter$CustomerPagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1408)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.get_Key$type$netagenda$ui$gwt$client$pages$backend$customers$presenter$CustomerPagePresenter$_annotation$$none$$(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1421)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl.access$12(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:1419)
    at netagenda.ui.gwt.client.gin.ClientGinjectorImpl$13$1.onSuccess(ClientGinjectorImpl.java:2768)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.runAsync(GWT.java:255)

Comment: 1. Accept some answers for your questions.
2. What happens when you write jQuery(className) instead of $wnd.jQuery(className)?

Comment: I got this error 
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): jQuery is not defined  Could be that i'm not adding correctly the library jquery ? but with add the script in gwt.xml is enough, true ?

Comment: That pretty much solves your question then, for some reason the jQuery library is not being picked up properly in the function you're trying to use it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved adding the files into the home.html file like that :

```
    <!-- jquery and plugins -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/javascripts/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
```

and after this is my method with gwt for call the plugin:

```
    public static native void allClassName(String className) /*-{
      $wnd.jQuery(className).tipsy({trigger: 'focus', gravity: 'w'});
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

In last versions of GWT you can't add javascript file in the module , you need to inject 
in your EntryPoint to this way:

In your EntryPoint Class:

```
ScriptInjector.fromString(PluginClientBundle.INSTANCE.plugins().getText())
        .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW)
        .inject();
```

Your Bundle class

```
public interface PluginClientBundle extends ClientBundle {
  static final PluginClientBundle INSTANCE = GWT.create(PluginClientBundle.class);

   @Source("resource/js/jquery-plugin.min.js")
   TextResource plugins();
}
```